# How do I scroll a PDF file with the help of a button

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to scroll up and down using a button in Android Studio but the app keeps crashing when I press the button. How do I solve this problem? I don't think I have the right code for this.

I've tried using a splash screen animation code to try making the scroll happen but it doesn't work.

```
    public class book1 extends AppCompatActivity {

             PDFView book1;
             Animation frombottom;
             LinearLayout menus;
             Button fab;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_book1);

             book1=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfbook1);
             fab=(Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
             menus = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menus);
             book1.fromAsset("Java Book1.pdf").load();

             fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
            frombottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(book1.this, R.anim.frombottom);
            book1.animate().translationY(-1900).setDuration(1800).setStartDelay(1300);

            menus.startAnimation(frombottom);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to show what crash you get, and include the stack trace.

Comment: Please do not use the "Android Studio" tag unless your question is specifically about your IDE. This seems to be a question about an app running on an Android app (or an emulator).